# How to update TeXstudio moderncv class

Tags: texstudio, moderncv

I wish to use moderncv `\social` command which is not recognized so I assume I have to update the class, how do I go about doing it with TeXstudio? I haven't downloaded any package for moderncv to begin with, just used `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}` and it worked, but the `\social` command is not recognized so I'm wondering on what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your TeX distribution (MiKTeX or TeX Live). TeXstudio is only the editor, the editor calls your TeX distribution to compile the code.

Check the first line of your resulting `.log` file, there you can read the used version of class `moderncv`. The current one is version 2.2.0.

Comment: I've reinstalled MikTeX to the latest version and updated all default packages.
Now when compiling I get a whole new set of errors:
`Package fontspec Error: The font "Latin Modern Math" cannot be found. \else`
`Font TU/LatinModernMath(0)/m/n/12="Latin Modern Math/OT" at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. \else`
It's opened the `moderncv.cls` file which is now updated but also have unrecognized commands like `\xetexorluatextrue`

Comment: seems to be fixed somehow by itself, by the command is still unrecognized according to TeXstudio but it actually works? It highlight it in red marker saying "unrecognized  command" yet it works, why is that?

Comment: @Jorayen How do you compile? With pdflatex or xelatex or lualatex? Check the configuration of your editor. Try to compile with pdflatex, then the fontspec error should  vanish ...

Comment: xelatex, and even with pdflatex I get unrecognized commands for /social even tho it works.

Comment: @Jorayen please check the log file, in the first line you can see the used version of class `moderncv`. Please tell me the used version. Without knowing this number I can not help you ...

Comment: @Jorayen your editor doesn't actually read the latex package at all, for some packages it may have been configured to mark some commands as known but if the package is updated the editor config will not automatically update, and in any case whetehr or ot the editor marks the command as known makes no difference to tex itself.

Comment: The package version is 2.2.0